# java static import

Tags: java

sometimes we can from ClassA do :

```
import com.software.ClassB;
    classbObject = new ClassB ;
    ClassB.getMethodX();
```

and we can also from ClassA make directly

```
import com.software.ClassB;
classbObject = new ClassB ;
classbObject.getMethodX();
```

what is the diffrence between these 2 cases (calling directly the class or the object)? is there one recommended?
thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean why this :

```
ClassB.getMethodX()
```

is different from this?

```
classbObject.getMethodX()
```

If so, then the second is somehow wrong. I mean it still works, but it makes no sense. The method is declared as static, which "belongs" to the class. You have one static method for a class, not matter how many instances. So, every static method should be called in a static way:
    ClassB.getMethodX()

Comment: Eugene, i've update my questionby adding classbObject = new ClassB ;

Comment: @lola the answer is still the same. Seems like your getMethodX() method is static right? And you are wondering how to call it, from Class or from Object? If so, then as I've said, from Class is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the same thing as I mean: no, there is no functional difference between `ClassB.getMethodX()` and `classbObject.getMethodX()` since the `getMethodX` is static. Only your compiler may give you a warning that `classbObject.getMethodX()` is discouraged because of the static method call from a non-static context.

Comment: I think it should be stated that even though there is no difference, calling a static method via an instance should be discouraged.

Comment: it is also discouraged, certain IDEs like Eclipse give a warning when done like this.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do `ClassB classbObject` without an import is if they are in the same package. If you are asking, should you use an import the answer is, use an import if it is required because the class is not in the same package.

I don't see a static import in your question so not sure how that relates to your question.